# Ext JS dynamically select build profile

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using Ext JS 6.2.0, and I've generated an application using Sencha Cmd.

In the "app.json", I created the following build profiles:

```
 /**
 * Build Profiles. This object's properties are each a "build profile". You can
 * add as many as you need to produce optimized builds for devices, themes, locales
 * or other criteria. Your "Ext.beforeLoad" hook (see index.html) is responsible for
 * selecting the desired build profile by setting "Ext.manifest" to one of these
 * names.
 *
 */

 "builds": {
    "aria_english":{
        "theme": "theme-aria",
        "locale": "en"
    },

    "neptune_chinese": {
        "theme": "theme-neptune",
        "locale": "zh_CN"
    },

    "gray_spanish": {
        "theme": "theme-gray",
        "locale": "es"
    }
},
```

I can select one of the build by running the cmd:

```
sencha app build aria_english
```

But I don't want to re-build the application to change the build profile. I'd like the selection of build profile based on URL or data from DB.

I looked at [Sencha's doc on Dynamic Manifest](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/microloader.html#microloader_-_dynamic_manifest). And added the following codes in "index.html", before the microloader.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Ext = Ext || {};
    Ext.beforeLoad = function (tags) {
        Ext.manifest = 'neptune_chinese';
    };
</script>
```

And I got the error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More]  bootstrap.js:1911:32

------------------update--------------------

I added the "manifest" setting in the "bootstrap" section of app.json.

```
"bootstrap": {
    "base": "${app.dir}",
    "manifest": "${build.id}.json",
    "microloader": "bootstrap.js",
    "css": "bootstrap.css"
},
```

Then, after I run the "sencha app build", a .json and .jsonp file are auto-generated for each profile (aria_english.json, aria_english.jsonp etc).

However, if I change the "Ext.manifest" to one of the profile name, the locale will change, but the theme will remain the same.

And I got error:

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
>   Location: http://localhost/buildTest/aria_english.json?_dc=1495764803737
>   Line Number 1, Column 1:  aria_english.json:1:1

Comment: Build you app with the **neptune_chinese** profile and rename/create  the "classic.json" to "neptune_chinese.json" similarly create other json files and make sure all files are deployed in production folder.